# Footnotes between subfigures in a standalone document class

Tags: footnotes, subcaption, standalone

In the following MCE, the footnote is between the first and the second sub-figures. Okay, the document class is `standalone` and the log warns me:

> LaTeX Warning: Nested minipage: footnotes may be misplaced on input line 11.

But how to workaround such an odd behavior?

```
\documentclass[varwidth=18cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Some dummy text with a footnote\footnote{This is the footnote's content.}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    First subfigure
    \caption{Caption of the first subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    Second subfigure
    \caption{Caption of the second subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    Third subfigure
    \caption{Caption of the third subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of the (global) figure}
\end{figure}

Some dummy text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why would you ever want footnotes in standalone? what do you want them to do?

Comment: Varwidth is a form of minipage, which is good since it allows footnotes.  However, it still uses `\insert\footins` which behaves mysteriously.  At the end of a minipage, **any** minipage, the footnote will appear.  Both subfigure and standalone figures are implemented as minipages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because of a weird request from the journal team (for whom I'm writing a LaTeX class): they want the (electronic) version of the articles to be on an endless single page (that may contain footnotes). I would like these footnotes to appear at the end of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a savebox to expand the minipages **before** the footnote.  Note that `\centering` does not do anything inside a varwidth.

```
\documentclass[varwidth=18cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\sbox0{\begin{varwidth}{18cm}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    First subfigure
    \caption{Caption of the first subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    Second subfigure
    \caption{Caption of the second subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    Third subfigure
    \caption{Caption of the third subfigure}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption of the (global) figure}
\end{figure}%
\end{varwidth}}

Some dummy text with a footnote\footnote{This is the footnote's content.}.

\noindent\usebox0

Some dummy text.
\end{document}
```